# How to redirect output window logs to a text file in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I wanted to save the output from the output window in a text file like shown below.

[image]

Currently I can use the logging function in SSIS to log stuffs. But I wanted the running processes output as well.

Is it even possible without using an exe like **dtexec** or a batch command?

Answer (score 0):

Start by executing your SSIS Package using [dtexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms162810(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with verbose reporting option, and redirect the content to a text file.

Comment: I cannot use dtexec. I have mentioned in my question. I am looking for an internal approach within SSIS to achieve this task.